# PDF Viewer using object tag not working for Edge

Tags: html, pdf, microsoft-edge

I am trying to show a PDF document inline using the object tag - it works as expected in Chrome and Firefox but isn't working in Edge.

Sample Code:

```
  <object id="pdfObj" data="http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf" type="application/pdf" target="_parent">
  </object>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/wH9ECcwkx3vHFv43xTo5?p=preview

What's a good way to show the PDF viewer in Edge? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which version of Edge are you using? I'm able to view embedded PDFs in Microsoft Edge 37.14316.1000.0. See here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/54DiU.png

Comment: Did u ever figure this out? I am still having issues

Answer (score 3):

I've faced a similar issue. Object tag behaves differently in IE and EDGE; the sever needs to accept the HEAD request made by the object tag (HEAD request : only in IE & EDGE) and give a response, then a get request is made to fetch the file.
This is a limitation in Microsoft's browsers.

Edit 1: This worked for me (EDGE and IE too) if I add the object tag html with the url in the data attribute to the dom instead of setting the attribute value, using javascript, of object tag which is already on the dom. Please note that I've a endpoint flushing response, this updates the value of data attribute.

Comment: I tried this as well, using a knockout if data-bind and only setting it to true after the object data element is populated and it is still not displaying anything. Can you show an example of your tag?

Comment: I got it to work by using knockout bindings with other browsers and jquery with IE/Edge ><.

Answer (score 3):

I replaced the value of the type attribute with **text/html**.

```
<object id="pdfObj" data="http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf" type="text/html" target="_parent"></object>
```

This method works for Edge and IE11.
The response of the <object> request contains html :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body style='height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin:0px; background-color: rgb(82, 86, 89);'>
        <embed style='position:absolute; left: 0; top: 0;'width='100%' height='100%' src='about:blank' type='application/pdf' internalid='5BD5603FA794B387B2B97F624FB9ABDE'></embed>
    </body>
</html>
```

Edge and IE11 maybe check the response content and block it because it is not a pdf...
The pdf is in the <embed> of the response.

Set **type** to **text/html** in this situation works for me on this browsers :

- Firefox
- Chrome
- IE11
- Edge
- Opera

I don't try on Safari.

I hope this answer has helped you and that my English did not bother you too much

Answer (score 2):

Changing the data is not going to work in EDGE until the bug is fixed. I found a workaround to remove the element and add a new element to its parent. It may not be for every situation, But it works for me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadPdf() {
            var viewer = document.getElementById("ScanPdf");
            var parent = viewer.parentElement;
            var newViewer = document.createElement("object");
            viewer.remove(); 
            newViewer.setAttribute("data", "your new url here");
            newViewer.style = oldStyle;
            parent.appendChild(newViewer);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<object width="1080" height="1080" id="ScanPdf" data="old url here"
        type="application/pdf" scanitemid="2317">ffff</object>
<button onclick="loadPdf()">LOAD PDF</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: More elegant would be to do the next:

const newViewer = viewer.cloneNode();
viewer.replaceWith(newViewer);

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: oldStyle is not defined