# Get access denied for PDF bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl on Edge browser

Tags: angular, pdf, microsoft-edge

### Current behavior

Can't open PDF file, `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl` give access denied for PDF on Edge browser

### Expected behavior

Should  view PDF file

### Minimal reproduction of the problem with instructions

This line  produce the issue

```
<object  [data]="pdfURL | safeUrl" > </object>
```

This line working ok
it works if PDF URL already written in the html

```
<object  data="https://pdfobject.com/pdf/sample-3pp.pdf" > </object>
```

this is the safeUrl pipe

```
@Pipe({ name: 'safeUrl'})
export class SafeUrlPipe implements PipeTransform  {
  constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(value) {
    return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
  }
}
```

### Environment

```
Angular CLI: 6.1.1
Node: 8.11.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 4.4.7
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router, tsc-wrapped


Browser:
- [x ] Edge version Default

For Tooling issues:
- Node version: XX  <!-- run `node --version` -->
- Platform:  Windows
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [PDF Viewer using object tag not working for Edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36725764/pdf-viewer-using-object-tag-not-working-for-edge)

We need to set the data attribute using DOM elementRef.

**Template:**

```
<object [data]="pdfurl | safeUrl" #pdfobject></object>
```

**Component:**

```
@ViewChild('pdfobject') pdfobject: ElementRef;
this.pdfobject.nativeElement.setAttribute('data', 'https://pdfobject.com/pdf/sample-3pp.pdf');
```

Comment: sorry i will test it when have time, if any one test it i will confirm the answer. thank you