# Base64 PDF data IE and Edge does not show up

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, base64

I have a PDF whose content is encrypted as a base64 string. I am trying to display it in an `embed` element. It works fine in Chrome and other browsers except Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer.

```
success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
  $("#url").html("");
  $("#url").append("<embed src=\"" + data.encodeUrl + "\" class=\"iframe\"></embed>");
  $("#cameraLink").modal('show');
}
```

Comment: Are you using a data URL in the `src`? If so these are [not well supported in IE and older versions of Edge](https://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri). It should work in Chromium based Edge, although I haven't tested this. I don't believe there's a workaround other than linking directly to the file itself.

Comment: blocked in IE due to security reason

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes, I have to use data URL in src. But what can be another way to show pdf except linking file directly?

Comment: Could it be the same problem than this ? Browser problems with Microsoft https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36725764/pdf-viewer-using-object-tag-not-working-for-edge

Answer (score 0):

The [Data Protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//cc848897(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) are supported only for the following elements and/or attributes:

- object (images only)
- img
- input type=image,
- Link
- CSS declarations that accept a URL, such as background, backgroundImage, and so on.

As far as I know, Internet Explorer and the legacy version of Microsoft Edge does not support the use of DATA URIs as the source of `iframe` or `embed` .

As an alternative workaround, in the IE browser and the legacy version of Microsoft Edge, I suggest you could download the PDF file first, then, using browser to display the PDF file.

You could refer to the following code:

```
function myfunction() {
    var data = "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";

    var fileName = "test.pdf";
    //For IE and the legacy version of Microsoft Edge, use atob convert base64 encoded data to byte array
    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        var byteCharacters = window.atob(data);
        var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
        var blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/pdf' });
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName); 
    } else {
        // Directly use base 64 encoded data for rest browsers (not IE and the legacy version of Microsoft Edge )
        var base64EncodedPDF = data;
        //var pdfWindow = window.open();
        //pdfWindow.document.write('<iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,' + base64EncodedPDF+'" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>');
        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.src="data:application/pdf;base64," + base64EncodedPDF;
        iframe.style ="width: 100%; height: 100%;"; 
        document.getElementById("content").append(iframe);
    }
}
```

Comment: We are facing same type of issue when loading html page in Office JS word Add-in with latest (Windows 10 1909 version) and (Office 365 16.0.11929.20586 64-bit version) which loads add-in in MS Edge. Also getting window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob as null/undefined. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my code, But it only works with newer version of EDGE and has same problem with older version of EDGE and I.E.

```
     success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
        $("#url").html("");
        if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) { 
            var pdfData = data.encodeUrl;
            if(pdfData!=null){
                var actualData = pdfData.split(',');
                var byteCharacters = atob(actualData[1]);
                var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
            }else{
                var actualData = pdfData;
                var byteCharacters = atob(actualData)
                var byteNumbers = new Array(pdfData.length);    
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
                byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
            }
            var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
            var blob = new Blob([byteArray], {type: 'application/pdf'});
            var blob_url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        $("#url").append("<iframe id='frame' class=\"iframe\</iframe>");

            var blob_iframe = document.querySelector('#frame');
            blob_iframe.src = blob_url;
        }else{
            $("#url").append("<iframe src=\""+data.encodeUrl+"\" 
                    class=\"iframe\" height="+height+" width=\"100%\"></iframe>");
        }
        $("#cameraLink").modal('show');
    }
```

Comment: Please check your code, in Edge and IE browser, we have to use the `window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);  ` method to download the pdf file first, then using browser to view the pdf file.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT  Yes you are right, But we are passing blob url in iframe as like this **"blob_iframe.src = blob_url"**. so it works fine here and shows pdf and image too.

Comment: Do you mean the pdf display well via the frame( in IE and Edge browser)? I have also checked it on my machine, it seems that in IE and Edge browser, I have to download the file first, then using the browser pdf viewer to view the PDF file, instead of using the IFrame tag. In the New Microsoft Edge, since it is chromium based, we could use the IFrame tag to display the pdf file. So, in my code the if statement doesn't contain the iframe elements, but the else statement contain it.

Comment: Pdf display well with the iframe only in new Microsoft Edge and it won't display in IE and older version of edge with Iframe. you have to download the file first, then using the browser's pdf viewer you can view the PDF file in older edge version and I.E.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
.then(
    pdf=> {
        let content = `data:application/pdf;base64, ${encodeURIComponent(pdf)}`;
        let pdfSrc = content;

        let html = `<object data="${pdfSrc}" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
                        <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="${pdfSrc}">
                        </iframe>
                    </object>`;

        let newPdfWindow = window.open("new window");
        newPdfWindow.document.write(html);
        this.loadingCF.next(false);
});
```

Using `<iframe>` wrapped inside the `<object>` tag, which i open in a new window.